# Fundamental Matrix of OED 3x3 Constant matrix

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, fundamental-solution

Given the constant matrix

A= \begin{bmatrix}4&-1&0\\3&1&-1\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}

find the fundamental matrix for the system $y'=Ay$.

After attempting to solve the system, I ended up with a general solution of the form,

$y(t) = C_1e^{2t}u + C_2e^{2t}v + C_3e^{2t}$

where u=
\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{bmatrix}

v=\begin{bmatrix}2+t\\3+2t\\1+t\end{bmatrix}

and w=
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{t^2}{2}+2t+2\\t^2+3t+2\\\frac{t^2}{2}+t+1\end{bmatrix}

could I get some feedback on this answer? Is it correct?

P.S. the $\frac{t^2}{2!}$ comes from generalizing the eigenvector, since it has an eigenvalue of 2, with multiplicity 3.

Comment: $$N = A -2I, e^{At} = I + t N + \dfrac{1}{2}t^2 N^2 =
e^{2t}\begin{bmatrix}
 \dfrac{t^2}{2}+2 t+1 & -\dfrac{t^2}{2}-t & \dfrac{t^2}{2} \\
 t^2+3 t & -t^2-t+1 & t^2-t \\
 \dfrac{t^2}{2}+t & -\dfrac{t^2}{2} & \dfrac{t^2}{2}-t+1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @Moo You should really put that in an answer.

Comment: That was actually my first answer, but I have no idea what possessed me to change it. @Moo

Comment: @amd: I think an earlier and nice answer you wrote can be used here, so go for it.

Comment: Have you checked your own answer at all? See if it actually does satisfy the equation.

Comment: I haven't but I'll try it out.